# How to call arrow function inside another function in php

Tags: php

How i can use arrow or anonymous function like this in php or something similar syntax to achieve this.

```
class calculator{
  // $sum = fn(...$args) => array_sum($args);
  public function hello(){
     // $sum(5, 10)
  }
}

or this way

$sum = fn(...$args) => array_sum($args);
class calculator{
  public function hello(){
     // $sum(5, 10)
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you use a global variable like `$sum` if it was not a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An arrow function in PHP is not a special kind of function, just a convenient syntax for declaring an "anonymous function" or "closure" - that is, a function which you can pass around as a normal variable.

So once you create your anonymous function $sum, it is just like any other variable - you have to pass that variable to where you need it. Normally, this is done so that you can change which function gets called by passing different functions in - think of something like registering an error handler, for instance.

Your first example is not legal PHP, because you can't declare a variable floating around in a class like that. Your second example is valid syntax, but the variable $sum has not been passed into the function, so doesn't exist there. A working (but not very useful) example would be this:

```
$sum = fn(...$args) => array_sum($args);
class calculator{
  public function hello(callable $functionToCall){
     echo $functionToCall(5, 10);
  }
}
$calc = new calculator();
$calc->hello($sum);
```

If all you're looking for is to add a sum method to the class, you don't need arrow syntax at all:

```
class calculator{
  public function sum(...$args) {
     return array_sum($args);
  }
}
```

Similarly, if all you want is a function named sum available everywhere, just declare it as a normal function, not a closure:

```
function sum(...$args) {
    return array_sum($args);
}
class calculator {
    public function hello() {
       echo sum(5, 10);
   }
}
```

Comment: I also found that using `global $sum;echo $sum(5, 10);` is working since `$sum` is a variable after all carrying the anonymous function with it. However, your suggested way seems to be better to me as this indicates loose coupling.

Comment: @nice_dev Yes, I decided not to mention global variables, as it can be tempting for learners to "cheat" and make everything global rather than understanding variable scope, leading to problems as programs get more complicated.

Comment: hey @nice_dev i also tried to use global but mine say `Value of type null is not callable` could you share your code

Comment: @IMSoP I definitely agree with you.

Comment: @KunalSharma See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/323b93fcd3e00fbc4bf7cbe65af06603a71e9a36

Comment: @KunalSharma Well, it depends on where you declared your variable. But generally, you're better off just not using global variables.

Comment: @IMSoP i just want to achieve loose coupling and short syntax which is easy to maintain and understand and php isn't helping me much :D

Comment: @KunalSharma Well, global variables are the opposite of loose coupling, they couple everything to a complex shared state. If you want loose coupling, you have to connect the pieces somewhere. Normally, that's done by passing objects into the methods or constructors of other objects; closures are really just a special case of that. If your $sum is global, it might as well just be a normal function, as in the last example I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) returns the output and stores the output to the variable of `sum`. As this is a normal variable of global scope, to use that variable, we should write `global $sum;` inside of `hello` method.

**Note** that here `sum` is a [closure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) of the arrow function.

The below code runs properly and provides the output 15.

```
$sum = fn(...$args) => array_sum($args);
 class calculator{
   public function hello(){
    global $sum;
    return $sum(5, 10);
   }
 }
$cal = new calculator();
print $cal->hello(); // Output 15
```

You can also use the global scope variable like this.

```
$sum = fn(...$args) => array_sum($args);
class calculator{
    public function hello(){
        return $GLOBALS['sum'](5, 10); // using the global variable
    }
}
$cal = new calculator();
print $cal->hello(); // Output 15
```